# How to protect against StreamReader.ReadLine( ... ) using too much memory?

Tags: c#, memory, streamreader

My app 'reads' text files line by line and processes the data as/when needed.
The reason I read one line at a time is, although most files are fairly small, some are actually rather large.

So, rather than reading everything into a single string and possibly running out of memory, I read the file line by line.

```
...
const string filename = /*get filename*/
using (var sr = new StreamReader(filename))
{
  string line;
  while ((line = await sr.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) != null)
  {
    //  process 'line'
  }
}
...
```

But looking at the, (.NET 4.7.2), code for `ReadLineAsync( ... )` there is also a possibility that the line in question could exhaust all the memory available, (in the case of a large file with no `'\n'` or `'\r'` in it).

The Beauty of `ReadlineAsync(...)` is that it takes care of all the Encoding and so on.

So my question is, how can I safely read a line **up to** a certain number of characters?

Comment: I don't believe you can. I think you would have to read byte by byte and determine if it's a new line or not and whether to continue reading to the same buffer or not

Comment: Don call readline, Call [other read async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) and add you too-much-data logic.

Comment: If reimplementing `ReadLine(Async)` from scratch is too daunting, you could always wrap `Stream` with a slightly more simple wrapper class that tracks the last time we saw a line separator, and either cuts the stream short or forcibly inserts a newline or raises some sort of event. Of course, this is not completely transparent to consumers. If exhausting all memory is a concern, you're probably better off devolving to solutions for that (Docker containers, job objects) instead of deciding that you get to determine what line length is OK.

Comment: Its not like you can't find a workaround for it,, but it just doesn't make much difference to your user.  She still has no data and a very awkward problem to solve, one that you can't do anything about yourself.  I suspect the *real* problem is a different one, it fails not because a line is too long but because the file contains too much data to process.  You most definitely have to fix that problem.  Just remove the jitter forcing, Project > Properties > Build tab, untick "Prefer 32-bit".

Comment: @All, I am happy to use `ReadAsync(...)` but the number of characters to read would depend on the encoding, (or does it take care of that?)

Comment: `StreamReader.ReadAsync` reads *characters*, not bytes. If you're going for an exact number of bytes, then the encoding matters. If you're only going for not exhausting memory, it doesn't really matter how many bytes X characters take up, as long as it's not all available memory (and no encoding is pathological enough to cause that). The main annoyance is having to do the buffer management for partial lines. (Having said that, the  new [`System.IO.Pipelines`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/07/09/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/) could help with that.)

Comment: Steal the source code for ReadLine and add a check...